# jsf file uploading issue in IE9

Tags: hibernate, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using jsf2.0 with primefaces.. In my application i have image uploading option. The file upload work fine all the browsers except IE9.. when i try to upload the file on IE9 i is not getting uploaded, and i am getting the following error.

Stack trace

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Eclipse_wspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ChennaiVolunteer\activityPhoto\C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at com.chennaivolunteer.photo.upload.PhotoUploadAction.handleImage(PhotoUploadAction.java:188)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:298)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:269)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:682)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesExecutor.execute(ApplyRequestValuesExecutor.java:34)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Aug 8, 2012 2:24:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

SE

my image.xhtml is

```
<f:view>
        <h:form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:panel  header="Event Images" style="font-size:12px;height:499px">
            <h:inputHidden value="#{photoUploadAction.aid}"></h:inputHidden>
            <p:messages id="messages" for="imaload"></p:messages>       
             <p:fileUpload id="imaload" fileUploadListener="#{photoUploadAction.handleImage}"  
                           mode="advanced"  multiple="true"
                          update="messages"  
                           immediate="true"  
                           allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  
                 <!--  <p:growl life="1000"  id="messages"/>  --> 
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
```

and my backing bean method is

```
    public void handleImage(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage;
        // setAid(getAid());

        String tmpFile = scontext.getRealPath(("/activityPhoto/")
                + event.getFile().getFileName());

        //File realPath = new File("e:/cv_project/ChennaiVolunteer/WebContent/activityPhoto",(event.getFile().getFileName()));
        File realPath = new File("d:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/ChennaiVolunteer/activityPhoto",(event.getFile().getFileName()));

        String filName = realPath.toString();

        /*File result = new File(tmpFile);

        String exactPath = result.toString();
*/
        byte[] imageByte = event.getFile().getContents();

        boolean flag = false;

        //storeImage(imageByte, tmpFile);

        String images = event.getFile().getFileName();
        photoUploadVO.setImageName(images);

        imageName = photoUploadVO.getImageName();

        if (loginBean.getType().equals("admin")
                || loginBean.getType().equals("ngo_coordinator")
                || loginBean.getType().equals("ngo")) {

            if (ngoPojo.getNgo_id() != 0) {
                photoUploadVO.setUsrId(ngoPojo.getNgo_id());
                photoUploadVO.setPhotoStatus("valid");
                photoUploadVO.setReasonForReject("pending");
                photoUploadVO.setUser_type(ngoPojo.getType());

            } else {
                photoUploadVO.setUsrId(loginBean.getUser_id());
                photoUploadVO.setPhotoStatus("valid");
                photoUploadVO.setReasonForReject("pending");
                photoUploadVO.setUser_type(loginBean.getType());
            }
        } else {
            photoUploadVO.setUsrId(loginBean.getUser_id());
            photoUploadVO.setPhotoStatus("pending");
            photoUploadVO.setReasonForReject("pending");
            photoUploadVO.setUser_type(loginBean.getType());
        }

        photoUploadVO.setCreated_by(loginBean.getEmail());
        photoUploadVO.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        photoUploadVO.setPhoto_path(tmpFile);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);

        // photoUploadVO.setUsrId(loginBean.getUser_id());
        // photoUploadVO.setActivityId(getAid());
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);


        if (bufferedImage.getWidth() <= 400 && bufferedImage.getHeight() <= 400) {

            photoUploadVO.setDisabled("false");
            getMthd(imageByte, tmpFile);

        } else {

            try {
                photoUploadVO.setDisabled("false");

                //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
                ImageIO.write(resize(bufferedImage, 400, 400), "jpg", new File(tmpFile));
                flag = photoUploadDaoService.uploadPhotos(photoUploadVO);

                // profileImageService.uploadPhotos(profileImageBean);
                if (flag == true) {
                    FacesMessage msg=null;
                    if(loginBean.getType().equals("admin")) {
                     msg = new FacesMessage("Successfully Uploaded");
                    }
                    if(!loginBean.getType().equals("admin")) {
                         msg = new FacesMessage("Successfully Uploaded(After administrator approve your photos will display on portal)");
                        }

                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                } else {
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failure", event
                            .getFile().getFileName() + " to uploaded.");

                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "The files were not uploaded!", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try updating to at least pf 3.2

Comment: i have tried pf 3.2 also ,still getting the same exception.. But i got whats the problem... event.getFile().getFileName() gives full path in IE9... so that the exception occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a security bug in IE. All IE versions sends the full client side file path instead of only the file name along with an uploaded file.

You should be using the Commons IO [`FilenameUtils#getName()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getName%28java.lang.String%29) to extract the file name from the full client side file path before using it in your code.

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(event.getFile().getFileName()));
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Apache Commons FileUpload FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html) - [Why does `FileItem.getName()` return the whole path, and not just the file name?](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that whole `tmpFile` variable is superfluous. You don't need it at all in the code given so far. Get rid of it altogether. It's also the wrong way to create a temp file. The `getRealPath()` may return `null` in some server configurations and is absolutely not intented to save files in, only to read files from.